# unable to print result line by line

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am unable to print result in line by line,it's coming in one line ,how to solve this....
I tried this code-

```
<script>
    function know(){
        var num =Number(document.getElementById('number').value);
        var range=Number(document.getElementById('range').value);
        var output="";
        var final=[];
        for(i=1;i<=range;i++)
        {output=i*num;
         final.push(output)
         final=final.replace(",","<br/>")}
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=final
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add more details, e. g. what are the `number` and the `range` elements?

Comment: Integer: 7
Range: 5
I want to show multiplication table like this-
7 * 1 = 7
7 * 2 = 14
7 * 3 = 21
7 * 4 = 28
7 * 5 = 35

"final" is the output result that I want to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 issues in it:

1. the for loop i you need to declare as a var or let(I recommend let)
2. there is no replace method in array, you can use map in this case

So you can re write the method like this.

```
<script>
    function know(){
        var num =Number(document.getElementById('number').value);
        var range=Number(document.getElementById('range').value);
        var output="";
        var final=[];
        //for(i=1;i<=range;i++)
        for(let i=1;i<=range;i++)
        {output=i*num;
         final.push(output)
         //final=final.replace(",","<br/>")
        }
        final = final.map((d, ind) => d*(ind+1))
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=final
}
</script>
```

Comment: Done by using=final = final.join(`<br/>`) instead of  final = final.map(d => d+"<br/>")  but how to get like 7 * 1 = 7 7 * 2 = 14 7 * 3 = 21 7 * 4 = 28 7 * 5 = 35 instead of only 7 14 21 28 35

Comment: For that you need to use map() function, map will be iterating over all values of that array(i.e. final) and you can use the index of map function to multiply and get your desired result.

ex:
final.map((d, ind) => {
  return d*(ind+1); //as index starts from 0 so doing a +1 here
}); 

I have updated my answer as well.